# Bath tub burping noise

Tags: water, bathtub

I noticed that our bath tub makes a burping noise sometimes when I wash my hands in the sink or flush the toilet

The noise sounds like (buk buk buk)

Note, we are in an apartment building, is this something we need to fix, or we can ignore?
Also note that this doesnt happen every time , but it does happen frequently

Thanks

Comment: Poor vent design or clogged vent line...

Comment: since this is an apartment building, is this vent something in my apartment, or in the building , and if in my apartment .. could it be just hair in the clogged in the tub, is this something i can fix myself?

Comment: It's not something you can fix unless you know what you're doing. The vent line is a line connected to your draining to let trapped air escape. If you take a soda bottle, fill it, and drain it by flipping it upside down, that "buk buk buk" sound you hear is basically what you are seeing: air is escaping in the same pipe as your water is escaping, and they're interfering with each other.

Comment: @Nelson is this something important to fix, or can i ignore it? 
also would those liquid that de-clog sinks and rain make any difference 
thanks

Comment: It's a design issue. If you find that your sink will overflow at full blast, use the valve under the sink to lower the maximum flow. Otherwise it is just an annoyance.